# Searching for a string a LARGE log-files

Tags: string, perl, unix, grep

Hello fellow programmers.
I am in need of a solution for a log-file issue.
This is a unix based environment. HP-UX.
There is a certain directory that contains log-files which are created daily and are appended as needed with messages and errors.
These files can be as large as 1GB of text.
I need to find a specific phrase.
How would you suggest me to do that?

System personnel advised me NOT to use simple GREP as it will cause high CPU usage during the search periods which are every 5 minutes.

What can I do in this case?

Comment: Maybe just parse the logfiles, store the data you need in a database
and index the columns you want to search on. grep is ideal for
one-offs or small text files. Maybe have a look at
[kibana](http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/kibana/) and
[logstash](http://logstash.net/) as well. If you'll parse and index
them periodically you're trading some disk space(for the index) and
the time it takes you to update the index(a small amount of time), and
in return you get very fast search queries. As a sidenote, this
question isn't necessarily related to Perl in my opinion.

Comment: How about the `File::Tail` perl module - you don't need to re-read the file every 5 minutes, but you can instead parse events as they arrive.

Answer (score 0):

If the phrase is only in one line, it is simple. Just read the file line-by-line and test the regexp on each line until you find it. 
Something like :

```
open(F, '<FILENAME>') or die "can't open file : $!";
while (my $line = <F>) {
    if ($line =~ /<MYREGEXP>/) {
        // regexp found
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [GNU parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) (see [the parallel `grep` example](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXAMPLE:-Parallel-grep)) to split the input in chunks and experiment with the `--jobs`, `--load` and `--nice` options.